# How to change the object names on sending response to api

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, angular, ajax

Upon creating the post I send this response to API

```
"postSummary":"Immediate",
   "locations":[
      {
         "spSubLocationCode":"CH1",
         "spSubLocationName":"IGT"
      }
   ],
```

Location is a dropdown which is retrieved location API where the names are defined as spSubLocationCode. But while posting a response to API they need it in the below format.

But api is expecting :

```
"announcementSummary":"Immediate",
"locations" : [{
    "locationCode":"terminalCode-9",
    "locationName":"terminalName-9"
}],
```

ts code

```
const publishReq = {              
  locations: postSummary.locations.filter(
    (val: string) => val != 'selectAlllocations'
  ),
  postType: postSummary.postType
};

createpost(publishReq)
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your last `filter` supposed to do. `postSummary.locations` is an array of objects, not an array of strings. But my first guess would be that you need to use a `map` operator after the `filter`

Comment: Where in your code does the `postSummary` come from? You only got a `postType`.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy solution is to just write a function that takes in your format and outputs the desired format:

```js
function toApiLocationCode(value) {
  // Here you will have to implement mapping from stuff like 'CH1' to 'terminalCode-9'
  switch (value) {
    case 'CH1':
      return 'terminalCode-9';
    calse 'IGT':
      return 'terminalName-9';
    default:
      throw Error(`Unknown location code: ${value}`);
  }
}

function toApiLocation(locationObject) {
  return {
    locationCode: toApiLocationCode(locationObject.spSubLocationCode),
    locationName: toApiLocationCode(locationObject.spSubLocationName)
  };
}

function toApiPayload(yourFormat) {
  return {
    "announcementSummary": yourFormat.postSummary,
    "locations": yourFormat.locations.map(toApiLocation)  
  };
}
```

This, however, is pretty dirty. And seeing you are using Typescript, it would be best to write classes and enums for this usecase:

```js
class DomainObject {

  constructor(
    public readonly postSummary: PostSummary,
    public readonly locations: Array<DomainLocation>
  ) {}

  public toApiObject() {
    return new ApiObject(
        this.postSummary, 
        this.locations.map(location => location.toApiLocation())
    );
  }
}

class DomainLocation {

  constructor(
      public readonly spSubLocationCode: string,
      public readonly spSubLocationName: string
  ) {}

  public toApiLocation() : ApiLocation {
      return new ApiLocation(
          mapDomainLocationCodeToApiLocationCode(this.spSubLocationCode),
          mapDomainLocationNameToApiLocationName(this.spSubLocationName)
      );
  }
}

enum PostSummary {
  IMMEDIATE = 'Immediate'
}

class ApiObject {

    constructor(
        public readonly announcementSummary: PostSummary,
        public readonly locations: Array<ApiLocation>
    ) {}
}

class ApiLocation {

    constructor(
        public readonly locationCode: string,
        public readonly locationName: string
    ) { }
}

function mapDomainLocationCodeToApiLocationCode(value: string) {
    switch (value) {
        case 'CH1':
            return 'terminalCode-9';
        default:
            throw new Error(`Location code '${value}' does not have an API code mapping.`);
    }
}

function mapDomainLocationNameToApiLocationName(value: string) {
    switch (value) {
        case 'IGT':
            return 'terminalName-9'
            default:
            throw new Error(`Location name '${value}' does not have an API name mapping`);
    }
}
```